# A word meaning "related to learning"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word I'd seen a bit ago in a textbook (I can't recall the textbook, maddeningly) that I found I quite liked. It is spelt something like **pedagous**, and it effectively means "written in a style suited for learning as opposed to a style more suited for use as a reference". Does anyone know what word it might be that I'm thinking of? Or alternatively a word that has a similar meaning?

Comment: Mnemonic?: or mnemonic device, is any learning technique that aids information retention. Mnemonics aim to translate information into a form that the brain can retain better than its original form.

Comment: @Josh61 Mmm, not quite in that sense. A book can be written to summarise an entire area, as for instance, Bourbaki's mathematics books did, or it can aim to allow learning. It's not necessarily meant as in aiding information retention, more for readability. The target audience is those who have not yet seen the topic.

Comment: I'm interpreting the word quite a bit, now, so I hope I'm not going past its actual meaning.

Comment: PEDAGOGICAL, that's the word! Like I said I was thinking past the meaning, but that is the context in which it was used.

Comment: In the browser at the Free Dictionary, _pedagogy_ is given 3 places above _pedal_.

Answer (score 1):

The word I was looking for was "pedagogical", meaning 'relating to educational methods and principles'. The writer described his book as being written in 'a more pedagogical style', or words to that effect.